# null pointer exception while using thread ang bufferedWriter

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to connect an arduino to my computer through java, i found the main code online that writes what arduino sends to stdo. I was wandering how to put that on a file and i created the "Scrittore" class, while using that without threads everything was fine, but while using it with the main code it gives me error:

```
**Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ricezionearduinoseriale.Scrittore.scrivi(Scrittore.java:32)
    at ricezionearduinoseriale.SerialTest$SerialReader.run(SerialTest.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)**
```

Could someone help me finding the bug or what I am doing wrong?(I just started working with java I am still quite a noob on that)

```
public class SerialTest{

public SerialTest()
{
    super();
}

void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    }
    else
    {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);
        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
            (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
        }
    }     
}

/** */
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
{
    InputStream in;
    Scrittore scrittura=new Scrittore();
    public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        try
        {
            scrittura.open("output.txt");
            //System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,len));
            while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
            {
                String out=new String(buffer,0,len);
                System.out.print(out);
                scrittura.scrivi(out);
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}

/** */
public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
{
    OutputStream out;

    public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {                
            int c = 0;
            while ( ( c = System.in.read()) > -1 )
            {
                this.out.write(c);
            }                
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}

public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        (new SerialTest()).connect("/dev/ttyACM0");
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Scrittore {
    FileWriter fw=null;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;
    public void open(String name){
        try{
            File file = new File(name);

    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            System.out.println("Aperto");
        }catch(IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();         
        }

    }
public void scrivi(/*String content*/) {//Skipped input while debugging
        String content="ciao";
        try{
           // System.out.println("Done");
    bw.write(content);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
}
    public void chiudi(){
        try{
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
        System.out.println("Chiuso");

    }
```

}

Comment: I strongly suspect that an exception is being thrown earlier - but you're mostly ignoring it as you catch lots of exceptions and just dump them to System.out, then continuing as if they never happened. That's almost *never* what you want to happen.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind but i didn't write that part though, the error is in scrivi() method while calling bw.write(content);, getting that away from the code removes the error

Comment: Well that just suggests that `bw` is null - which could easily be because the method which assigns a non-null value to `bw` failed.

Comment: I tried the code also on a separated project(without threads) and it works without giving errors and the file is created or edited, is it possible that the thread is interfering with FileWriter&BufferedWriter?

Comment: I wouldn't like to speculate, but I'd say the very *first* thing to do is fix the exception handling. Most of the methods should just declare that they throw IOException, and not catch anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bw,fw variable in scrivi function and chiudi function which are private variable of class ,while in open function you have used a temporary variable declared as

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

I believe this line should be,

```
fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

Hope, this helps.....